# easymock how to mock / set public final variable

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, easymock

I have class following class to test with mock objects.

```
public class FordFulkerson {

FlowNetwork network;
Search searchMethod;    

public FordFulkerson (FlowNetwork network, Search method) {
    this.network = network;
    this.searchMethod = method;
}

public boolean compute () {
    boolean augmented = false;
    while (searchMethod.findAugmentingPath(network.vertices)) {
        processPath(network.vertices);
        augmented = true;
    }
    return augmented;
}

protected void processPath(VertexInfo []vertices) {
    int v = network.sinkIndex;

    // Determine the amount. Goal is to find the smallest 
    int delta = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    while (v != network.sourceIndex) {
        int u = vertices[v].previous;

        // Over a forward edge, 
        int flow;
        if (vertices[v].forward) {
            flow = network.edge(u, v).capacity - network.edge(u, v).flow;
        } else {
            flow = network.edge(v, u).flow;
        }

        if (flow < delta) { delta = flow; }

        v = u;  // follow reverse path to source
    }

    // push minimal increment over the path
    v = network.sinkIndex;
    while (v != network.sourceIndex) {
        int u = vertices[v].previous;

        if (vertices[v].forward) {
            network.edge(u, v).flow += delta;
        } else {
            network.edge(v, u).flow -= delta;
        }

        v = u;  // follow reverse path to source
    }

    Arrays.fill(network.vertices, null);   // reset for next iteration.
}
}
```

My tests:

```
public class FordFulkersonMockTest {
private FordFulkerson classUnderTest;
private FlowNetwork mockNetwork;
private Search mockSearch;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    mockNetwork = createMock(FlowNetwork.class);
    mockSearch = createMock(Search.class);
    classUnderTest = new FordFulkerson(mockNetwork, mockSearch );

}

@Test
public void test01() {
    expect(mockSearch.findAugmentingPath(null)).andReturn(false);

    replay(mockSearch);
    boolean res = classUnderTest.compute();
    assertEquals(false, res);
    verify(mockSearch);
}


@Test
public void test02() {
    expect(mockSearch.findAugmentingPath(null)).andReturn(true);
    try{
        Field f = mockNetwork.getClass().getDeclaredField("sinkIndex");
        f.setAccessible(true);
        f.set(mockNetwork, 0);
        f = mockNetwork.getClass().getDeclaredField("sourceIndex");
        f.setAccessible(true);
        f.set(mockNetwork, 0);
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        fail(e.getMessage());
    }
    replay(mockNetwork);
    replay(mockSearch);
    boolean res = classUnderTest.compute();
    assertEquals(true, res);
    verify(mockSearch);
}

}
```

Test01 works fine, but in Test02 I have problem.
In Test02 method processPath needs to be called. It uses mockNetwork public final variables. I have no idea where to set them. It caused null exceptions. In code up there I tried to change accesability to this fields and set them but now I have error with message "sinkIndex".

How to mock public final variables in mockNetwork?
Im using Easymock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said you modified `FlowNetwork`'s source, so you can do the following which will result in more robust design, and easier testablity:

1. Encapsulate those two variables (i.e. `private int sinkIndex` and `int getSinkIndex()`)
2. `expect(mockNetwork.getSinkIndex()).andReturn(0).anyTimes();`

Guess: `mockNetwork.getClass()` is returning a cglib EasyMock proxy which has no state (i.e. no fields), you can check it in the debugger. Hence `getDeclaredField()` is returning `null`.

If you really want to use `public`s, you can try `FlowNetwork.class.getDeclaredField` instead.

Comment: No, I can't change source. Thats the problem. I tried to change accessability to them inside Test02.

Comment: Ahh I see, you just meant `setAccessible`, did you try my last edit? Also you can try not mocking the network, then `f.set` must work.

Comment: I need to mock network, its abstract. And I tried your last edit. 
Now I have Null pointer exception at Arrays.fill(network.vertices, null); (same as without changing variales)

Comment: Ok I've dealed with that. I also needed to set vertices same as this both variables. Thanks

Comment: Yep, every field of any object returned from `createMock` is `null` (or default primitive).